# Replicate mysql table to hive in Java Webapp

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am having a table in mysql. I want to make a copy of it in hive.
The programming language I am working upon is java. I have to perform this in a webapp. So I successfully made connection to both database via JDBC. Now the problem is how can I export-import the table?

1. Manual Loading - Export MySQL Table as csv data and Import that csv data to Hive tables. Which is looking feasible to me right now  somewhere for the implementation. But not the Ideal Solution.
2. Sqoop: Cant able to find a feasible implementation of it so I can perform inside a webapp.
3. Tungsten Replicator: I found and read about it. Looks good. But still searching for implementation via webapp.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop comes with java api which can be integrated in your web app to make connection.                              Please go through the below link to get more details:           http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.2/ClientAPI.html.